# Cytoscape disappearing edges with bezier curves and nodes moving/longer labels in nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape with bezier curves but edges are disappearing when having a node with longer label or just moving source node next to target node.

- Video: https://www.screencast.com/t/N2f5eZ5M7
- Runnable sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vpl72r?file=index.html

I have already seen "Edge xxxxx has invalid endpoints and so it is impossible to draw" warning and searched corresponding [threads](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2230) but couldn't find a solution.

Does anyone know how to handle that ?

Comment: 1. you shouldn't create new cytoscape instances on each call
2. this seems like a deeply related to cytoscape. If you drag "level 2" the edge appears and then disappears. This show there is signs deep problems inside cytoscape.js

Comment: thanks canbax! Reinitialization is just for illustration purposes. Yes, issue is reproducible with nodes dragging as well. I have filed an issue to cytoscape as well. For the time being I am increasing rank separation but wondered whether there is another approach for handling that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some warnings on the console

> The style value of `label` is deprecated for `width`
>
> The style value of `label` is deprecated for `height`

After I deleted `'width': 'label', 'height':'label',` I no longer observe such problem.

--- Update 1.1 ---

> but I'd like to have node's dimensions based on label's dimensions.

To do this I think you should write a function style. See the below example. In the example, you can see that we are setting the size of the nodes dynamically based on their `name` length. I assumed `name` is a string that stores labels.

```
cy.style().selector('node').style({
      'width': (x) => { return x.data('name').length + 'px;' }
      'height': (x) => { return x.data('name').length + 'px;' }
    }).update();
```

Comment: Thanks canbax! This resolves the issue, but I'd like to have node's dimensions based on label's dimensions.